# Double branched covers of $S^3$ branched along prime knots

Tags: knot-theory, low-dimensional-topology

Let $M(k)$ denote the double branched cover of $S^3$ along the knot $k$. It is known that $M(k_1\#k_2)=M(k_1)\#M(k_2)$. It is also known that the unknot is the only knot such that the corresponding double branched cover is $S^3$. These two facts together imply that the double branched cover of $S^3$ along a non-prime knot is a non-prime 3-manifold. I wonder if the converse is true. More precisely, is it true that if $k$ is a prime knot, then $M(k)$ is prime?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you think of $(S^3, k)$ as an orbifold with singular set $k$ (and cone angle $\pi$ along $k$), then you should think about orbifold covers - eg the double branched cover - of this as analagous to covers of 3-manifolds themselves. And you know that covers of prime 3-manifolds are still prime (though the converse is not necessarily true). So you should try to mimic that proof. The way this usually works is by passing through irreducible 3-manifolds.

Suppose the branched double cover is not irreducible, so there is a sphere that does not bound a ball. Then (Meeks-Simon-Yau; [Dunwoody](http://blms.oxfordjournals.org/content/17/5/437.extract)) there is a sphere $S$ that does not bound a ball, intersects $\tilde k$ in as few points as possible, and the involution $\iota$ either has $\iota S = S$ or $\iota S \cap S = \varnothing$. Let's look at the two cases separately.

1) $\iota S \cap S = \varnothing$. Since $\tilde k$ is the fixed point set of the involution, clearly this implies $S$ is disjoint from $\tilde k$. Push the sphere $S$ downstairs; this implies its image is a sphere disjoint from $k$. Because spheres in $S^3$ bounds a ball on both sides, pick the ball disjoint from $k$. Then $f^{-1}(B) \to B$ is again a double cover, and thus $f^{-1}(B)$ is two disjoint balls, so $S$ bounded a ball after all. Whoops.

2) $\iota S = S$. Every involution of $S$ is either the identity or conjugate to the antipodal map, rotation by $\pi$ around an axis, or reflection across a plane. It cannot be either the identity or the reflection, since then it would not intersect the fixed point set $\tilde k$ transversely. If it were the antipodal map, the image would be an embedded $\Bbb{RP}^2$ in $S^3$, which is impossible. So all that's left is that $S$ intersects $\tilde k$ at exactly two points, and so $S$ passes downwards to a sphere that intersects $k$ at exactly two points. If $k$ is prime, then one of the balls $S/\iota$ bounds must intersect $k$ in an arc, and thus the double branched cover of that ball is a ball, contradicting the choice of $S$.

So the double branched cover of a prime knot is irreducible and thus prime.

Comment: Thanks, Mike. I have two questions. (1) How do we know that either $\iota S=S$ or $\iota S \cap S = \varnothing$? Is that true in general for all involutions and spheres, or do we use anything special about the sphere and the involution? (2) I don't understand the reasoning to reach ''$S$ intersects $\tilde k$ at exactly two points''. Should I take this as "No essential sphere cuts $\tilde k$ at more than two points"? It sounds too strong even though I can't come up with a counter-example.

Comment: (1) The theorem I linked is that there exists such an essential sphere. (2) Since the knot is the fixed point set, and $\iota S = S$, the fixed points of $\iota$ correspond bijectively to intersection points of the knot. Since we reduced to the case that the involution on the sphere is an appropriate rotation, which. has two fixed points, we conclude.